# Azure storage table copy

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-table-storage

I have a problem using azure AzCopy. Here my scenario.
I have 2 storage accounts, which I am gonna name storage1 and storage2.

Storage1 contains some important data in multiple tables, what I want to do..is to be able to copy all the tables in storage1 to storage2 (having a backup).

I tried 2 different approaches:

- AzCopy
- Azure Data Factory

With `Azure Data Factory` I didn't have any particular problem to make it work, I was able to move all the blobs from storage1 to the `data Factory` but I I couldn't move the tables and have no clue if this is possible to do it with python.

with `AzCopy` I had zero luck. I gave myself permission in IAM `Blob Storage Data contributor` and from the terminal when I run this command:

`azcopy cp 'https://storage1.table.core.windows.net/Table1' 'https://storage2[...]-Key'`

I got the permission error.

In this specific scenario I would love to be able to use AzCopy as is way more simple than data factory as all what I need is to move those table from one storage to the other.

Anyone who can help me out to understand what am I doing wrong with azCopy please?

EDIT:
This is the error when I try to copy the table using azcopy

```
INFO: The parameters you supplied were Source: 'https://storage1.table.core.windows.net/[SAS]' of type Local, and Destination: 'https://storage2.table.core.windows.net/[SAS]' of type Local
INFO: Based on the parameters supplied, a valid source-destination combination could not automatically be found. Please check the parameters you supplied.  If they are correct, please specify an exact source and destination type using the --from-to switch. Valid values are two-word phases of the form BlobLocal, LocalBlob etc.  Use the word 'Blob' for Blob Storage, 'Local' for the local file system, 'File' for Azure Files, and 'BlobFS' for ADLS Gen2. If you need a combination that is not supported yet, please log an issue on the AzCopy GitHub issues list.

failed to parse user input due to error: the inferred source/destination combination could not be identified, or is currently not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy all the tables which is present is abc container to xyz container. Use simple copy acitivty and while creating dataset just give folder path that copy all the content i.e all the tables to your xyz container.

I would like to watch below video from the 30th mins. It will help in your scenario.
https://youtu.be/m6wyB-Hm3j0